# Can I find all stored procedures that contain a certain column in DB2?

Tags: sql, plsql, db2

I'm trying to find out all stored procedures that contain a certain column in DB2. I have been trying to do something like this but there is no `syscat.colname` in `syscat.procedures`.

```sql
select *
from syscat.procedures
where syscat.colname like '%FLAG%'
```

Do you guys have any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean, SQL procedures that mention a specific column-name ? Or that modify or read a specific column?   Also which Db2-server platform ( z/os , i series  , linux / unix /windows /cloud ?)

Comment: Provide an example of such a Stored Procedure you are looking for, one that should be found and one that should be excluded. The text of SPs is stored and you could apply a regex in certain cases.

Comment: SQL procedures that mention a specific column name and I am using Dbeaver as a tool, not sure how to check which platform I am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only want to check if the procedure text mentions a column name.

For recent versions of Db2 for linux/unix/windows (Db2-LUW), you can try something like this:   (replace **COLNAME** by the name you seek ):

```
select cast(rtrim(procschema)|'.'||rtrim(procname) as varchar(128) ) as procname
from syscat.procedures
where dbms_lob.instr(text , varchar('COLNAME'), 1) > 0
order by 1
with ur;
```

Notice that the search is case sensitive so you will need to adjust if you need case insensitivity.

This query will not guarantee that the column is used in SQL for insert/update/delete/select - for example the column name might be referenced in a remark or be part of a variable name. Other catalog tables contain dependent object information for static-SQL packages.